# Tried to move a file and now i cant find it

Tags: command-line, mv

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and I had a file name `__app.zip` and I was wanting to move that inside the folder name `testing`

To move the file i used the following command after which I cant find the file anymore, from searching online I understand now that i did not need to put `/` before the folder name.

```
sudo mv __apps.zip /testing
```

Is there anyway to get the lost file back?

Comment: It will be in your root directory,  `/testing `

Comment: @Ron sorry really new to terminal system here. suppose if the file was inside `/var/www/html/domain_name.com/subdomains/demo/` then what will be the root?

Comment: It is the top most directory. See its contents with `ls -l  /`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You renamed your file `testing` in the root directory `/` with your command.

To move it back to where it was, just move it again:

```
sudo mv /testing /var/www/html/domain_name.com/subdomains/demo/__apps.zip
```

Comment: when you say root directory, what directory in that? My file was inside `/var/www/html/domain_name.com/subdomains/demo/`

Comment: The root directory is `/`. If you want to restore your file  :

`sudo mv /testing /var/www/html/domain_name.com/subdomains/demo/myfile.zip`